# How could I track how many times a thumbnail is viewed in Shopify collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I'm trying to figure out how to track how many times a product thumbnail is actually *viewed* in a given Shopify collection.

i.e. once a user scrolls past a thumbnail, the *viewed* count would go up by 1. (Not the same as page impressions because products at bottom of collection might not be viewed).

Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: This is ambitious ! You will need a strong Javascript piece of code to detect when an image has been seen, then make an AJAX call to tell your server which images had been seen and save it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with either the WayPoints plugin or Bootstrap's Affix. You'd need to tag your images appropriately and then perhaps use Google Analytics to track the images. Otherwise you'd need something like GA to receive notices of images viewed (or at least images scrolled past :)